# Does 'sudo' extend its timeout every time you use it?

Tags: sudo

If I use `sudo`, and type my password in, I can continue to use `sudo` without my password for 15 minutes.

I know (per `man sudoers`) that I can edit the timeout by setting the `timestamp_timeout` value in `/etc/sudoers`. That's not my question.

My question is this: is that timeout counted from the first time I use sudo, or is it refreshed every time I use sudo?

```
sudo foo    # at T; prompts for a password
sudo bar    # at T+10m; no password required
sudo baz    # at T+20m; does this prompt?
```

Answer (score 1):

It's restarted every time you enter a sudo command. This is easy to test. Try setting the timeout to like 2 minutes... if you don't have your timeout extended when you redo a sudo command within 15 seconds of the timeout ending (Try using an egg timer or whatever), then I'm wrong :)